# What do double double quotes do when used in an expression in Java?

Tags: java

Here's an example that I'm looking at

```
public static BigInteger factorial(long n) {
 BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
 result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));

 return result;
```

What does it do in the BigInteger(i + ""))?

Comment: Do you know what strings are? Do you know how to write a string literal? Do you know what adding a string to a non-string produces? Put those pieces of information together, and you'll see what `i + ""` does.

Comment: it is the **wrong** way to implicitly get the string representation of a number, never do this. `String.valueOf()` is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) constructor takes a `String` argument, not an `int`.

`i + ""` coerces `i` to a `String` data type so that it can be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

That is the short way to convert an int to String object. They do that because the constructor of BigInteger doesn't receive an int as parameter.

You can look the javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Since the expression is inside a for, the better way must be:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
 result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

Because the constructor that uses the String is useful when you are trying to represents numbers bigger than 64 bit signed int (2^63 - 1)

Comment: Doesn't `BigInteger.valueOf(i)` work?

Comment: You're right and looking the soruce code is the best way